# XCODE IDE update 8.1 issue, Appstore not recognising my current installation

Tags: xcode, ide

I have installed the existing one from the App store only but, I dunno why it's not sensing it. I tried refreshing my updates in App store still nothing happened. My Os is up to date and I can also directly install Xcode 8.1 but I would prefer to just update from 7.3.1 to 8.1. In app store I get the option to GET or INSTALL instead of UPDATE. Thanks in advance

Comment: I found out that, even now i.e. Xcode 10 still has issues, when I had to update it only works sometimes after you delete the current installation in Applications through finder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a well know issue, some say that Apple prefers you to reinstall the whole Xcode program each time it updates, there are really few incremental updates as far as I'm concerned. 
By the way I don't really think this question belongs to StackOverflow, you should rather put it on http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for the heads up